# Increase space between ytick labels and confusion matrix

Tags: matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I want to increase the space between ytick labels and the confusion matrix (as in the red bracket in the figure).

I tried different options by `labelpad` or `pad` alike but didn't work out.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
    
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
  """
  This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
  Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
  """
  import itertools
  if normalize:
      cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
      print("Normalized confusion matrix")
  else:
      print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

  plt.close()
  plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
  plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 9, 9
  mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Avenir'
  plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18
  plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2
  plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']= 100
  plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad']= 100
  plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
  plt.title(title, pad = 25)
  plt.colorbar()
  tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
  plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
  plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)
  plt.ylabel('True label', labelpad=10)
  plt.xlabel('Predicted label', labelpad=10)

  fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
  thresh = cm.max() / 2.
  for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
      plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                horizontalalignment="center",
                color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

  plt.tight_layout()


myarray = np.array([[ 6,  4,  2,  0],
                       [ 4, 57,  3,  0],
                       [ 4,  3, 12,  0],
                       [ 4,  3,  0,  0]])

plot_confusion_matrix(myarray, ["a","b","c","d"])
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try upgrading to the latest matplotlib version (3.4.1)?

Comment: It worked. Thanks!